# How to specify data type in XML-RPC response memeber?

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I'm producing XML-RPC response through java server and I want following output in produced response

```
        <member>
            <name>Time</name>
            <value>
                 <dateTime.iso8601>2019-04-24T12:25:16.725Z</dateTime.iso8601>
            </value>
        </member>
```

but all I'm getting in response is

```
        <member>
            <name>Time</name>
            <value>2019-04-24T12:25:16.725Z</value>
        </member>
```

I used Java Hashtable object and set key-value pair. As below

```
Hashtable result = new Hashtable();
result.put("Time", Instant.now().toString());
```

What am I missing to specify `<dateTime.iso8601>` in between `<value>` tag? Do I need to explicitly define it? and if so How?

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved data type issue

Need to specify **java.util.Date** object

```
Hashtable result = new Hashtable();
result.put("Time", Date.from(Instant.now()));
```